# Cannot access instances of openstack on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, openstack, network-connection

I've openstack(single node) installed on an AWS instance. I can log into the openstack dashboard and I'm also able to spawn instances but, I'm not able to connect via SSH or ping those instances.
In the security group setting section, I've allowed all types of protocols for the instances.

Comment: Do you assign the ssh key pair on that instance ?

Comment: yes. I generated and then assigned the ssh key pair to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

SSH into the AWS instance first, from there you can access the openstack instances.

If you need your spawned instances to be available over the public internet, you need to [manage your public (floating) IPs](http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/content/nova-associate-public-ip.html).